# how to write selected checklistboxitems in a folder

Tags: c#

i am having a problem in writing selected checklistbox items in a text file .

i am having 2 or more than source path ,i wanted to write the selected checklistbox items source path in a single
destination because there are many subfolders i cant select it one by one the folder contain more than 75 folders
so i want to write the files by selecting  checklistbox items.Is it possible or there is any other code.

i use this line to write the folders.

checkedListBoxlastrecored.Text = v[0];

this line only writes single path folder checkedListBoxlastrecored.Text

for example there are three subfolders in E:\

checkedListBoxlastrecored.Text = v[0]; \ this line writes only the single selected path

E:\amex\a-l \ this is the single path which is working
E:\amex\dead 
E:\amex\m-z

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to put a list of file names in a CheckedListBox, and you want this list to include all the files in a specified directory and all of its subdirectories, recursively. If this is the case, then this code will do the trick:

```
    private void getFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        filesCheckedListBox.Items.Clear();
        PopulateWithFilesRecursively(directoryTextBox.Text, filesCheckedListBox, string.Empty);
    }

    private static void PopulateWithFilesRecursively(string sourceDirectory, CheckedListBox checkedListBox, string relativeDirectory)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory))
        {
            checkedListBox.Items.Add(Path.Combine(relativeDirectory, Path.GetFileName(file)));
        }

        foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDirectory))
        {
            PopulateWithFilesRecursively(directory, checkedListBox, Path.Combine(relativeDirectory, Path.GetFileName(directory)));
        }
    }
```